# How to find greatest frequency of substring in string with no spaces

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

lets suppose string is like "aababcabcdabcdeabcdefabcdefg". so how to find the frequency of largest (all possible) substring.

ps: there is no spaces in between the string.

Comment: the ___largest substring___ would be the string only and frequency 1

Comment: largest substring is the string itself and its frequency is 1. what are you asking actually?

Comment: Don't get it, the "largest substring" that could possibly be, is itself, and therefore has a frequency of 1 (unless I'm missing something.) Do you mean the *largest substring with the highest frequency*?

Comment: how is a substring defined by you? everything is a substring, no matter how long. whats allowed in a substring and what is not allowed?

Comment: Your definition of substring is still not clear. give a proper test case, a String, the expected largest substring according to you (and why?) and its count..

Answer (score 0):

```
String stArray[] = s.split("\\s+");
int large =0;
String largeSt="";
for(int i=0;i<stArray.length;i++)
 {
    if(stArray[i].length() >large)
        {
          largeSt=stArray[i];
          large = stArray[i].length();
         }
 }
system.out.println("very large :"+largeSt);
if you want to find frequency just count from array by matching
```